# How to use a combo box as a directory path

Tags: c#, combobox, cpu-word

I have 4 combo boxes that are linked to a server folder that show all the .dotx available on the folder.

string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"location of the folder", "*.dotx");

```
        foreach (string file in files)
            comboBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(file));
        foreach (string file in files)
            comboBox2.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(file));
        foreach (string file in files)
            comboBox3.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(file));
        foreach (string file in files)
            comboBox4.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(file));
```

I am using the code in this video "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0me-ntfD8Rk" with some minor changes.

I am a total newbie in c# and programming in general, I'm just trying to understand how I can make my directory path in my button (see video at 16:13) to be the directory chosen by the user in the combo box1 per example.

Any guidance would be really appreciated.

Comment: did you try downloading the code that is referenced on the YouTube link? - https://www.madsycode.com/download/vspoject/

Comment: @Dhawalk yes i am using it and the code is working when it comes to replacing the text in the document that has its path set. however i dont want to set a "fixed" path i want that the path chosen by the user in combo box1 is the path of the docx used in the code. thats where im stuck

Comment: Let's suppose you only have 1 combo box. Do you still have a problem? "How can I make my directory path in my button" <-- you cannot. Please be clear on what exactly you want, and how directory path, button and combo box relate to each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I believe you're asking is how to reference the selected item in the combo box? If so you can simply do this:

```
comboBox1.Text
```

So in the video at 16:13 the call to the method would look like:

```
CreateWordDocument($"path\\of\\directory\\{comboBox1.Text}", @"path\to\output")
```

Where `$"{variableName}"` is a bit of shorthand that lets you reference a variable insde a string.

As a side note, you don't need to call the same loop four times like that. Instead it can look like:

```
foreach(string file in files)
{
    string path = Path.GetFileName(file); // Note I can call GetFileName once and reuse the result
    comboBox1.Items.Add(path);
    comboBox2.Items.Add(path);
    comboBox3.Items.Add(path);
    comboBox4.Items.Add(path);
}
```

Comment: thats some pretty nice stuff! it's working now i had to change the string from file to filepaths but you solved the question! much thanks now im gonna do my own research and try to finish this project. thanks man!

Comment: Yeah sorry, I glossed over the fact that is was FileNAME as opposed to the full path, though I made an edit to reflect that when I realised. Happy to help!